# Custom radio button - edge bleed-thru

Tags: android

I have an eCommerce app for which  I have designed a color selection piece.  I use a custom RadioButton and RadioGroup to select a single color.  I download the possible color swatches from the server  and paint the background of each button.

The problem is that for dark colors, the underlying image bleeds through and a faint line is visible around the edges.

It looks like this:

[image]

I defined my custom button with this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



<item android:state_checked="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/color_radio_unselected" />

<item android:state_checked="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/color_radio_selected"/>

</selector>
```

and the two pieces of that are:

[image]
[image]

and then I programmatically paint the background in Java like this:

```
color = new RadioButton[MAX_COLORS];
    color[0]= (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.color0);
    color[1] = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.color1);
    color[2] = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.color2);
    color[3] = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.color3);
    color[4] = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.color4);

<snip>

Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),productDetails.colorSwatchBM.get(thisColor));
        if (sdkVersion < 16) {
           color[i].setBackgroundDrawable(d);
        }
        else {
            color[i].setBackground(d);
        }
```

The color swatches I get from the server are only 27x27 pixels and the radiobutton images, after Android brings them in scales them, are about 53x53. It looks like it's scaling the background to the same size as the button, but then the colors are aliased together

Anyone know how to make the edges not be so visible?

Thanks!

Comment: have you changed the default type of drawables? ,e.g :.png to .jpg

Comment: the incoming color swatches are indeed jpg already. However, my custom buttons are png.  I can try that if you think it will help.

Comment: but, because of the transparency (the center is transparent to show the color swatch) I can't use jpg :(

Comment: just Check them with .png once,i hope that might work , atleast we will find if there is some other reason

Comment: I was wrong, the server images are png, not jpg. But I can't change those anyway

Comment: well, I dealt with this one on my own.  I ended up pulling out a single pixel from the color swatch image and then using drawCircle to render a circle of that color within a canvas using a mutable bitmap. I could then take that bitmap and keep the edges clean.  Hard way to go, but it worked

Comment: I Think, there will be some easy way to do it , The overall problem was in the drawable but it is good you solved it programmatically